# How to show the whole table content from backendless?

Tags: reactjs

For simplicity I've reduced the code, problem here is I've a bunch of data and I've to retrieve it. But when I try to do it it is just displaying the first entered value. I want all the values to be showed. If you want more elaborated code means just comment down. I will paste it.

```
class Main extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchTableContent().then(result=> (console.log(result.payload),this.setState({rows:result.payload})))
}

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
           rows:this.props.table
        }
    }
render(){
    return(
         <tbody>
             { _.map(this.state.rows,(row,index)=>{
                 return(
                      <TableItems
                          key={index}
                          index={index}
                          row={row}
                          />
                        );
                    })
                    }
          </tbody>)}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {table: state.table};
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps,{fetchTableContent})(Main);
```

TableItems

```
 <tr>
       <th scope="row" className="mycheckbox"><input type="checkbox"/><label></label></th>
        <td>{this.props.row.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.row.avgGrade}</td>
        <td>{this.props.row.occupation}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for 'TableItems'?

Comment: Updated the content, just these are there under render. @SteveBohmbach

Comment: youre attempting to map over 'this.state.row' and pass each item in it to 'TableItems' correct?

Comment: Yeah exactly...

Comment: Does the store initially have all the values? Or does it fetch all the values from an endpoint?

Comment: It fetches all the values from the endpoint.  @ThiagoMurakami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided code, you're:

1. Making an API call in `componentDidMount`. Because of the `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`, I will assume you're using Redux as well.
2. Initializing `this.state.rows` from the props passed from `connect`.
3. Using `this.state.rows` to render the `TableItems`.

In your code, I don't see where the data coming from `this.props.fetchTableContent()` is updated to the component, because you don't call `this.setState()` to update it.

I think you can:

1. Use `this.props.table` directly if you don't have a strong reason not to.
2. Use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to update the component's state every time `this.props.table` is updated.

Using my first suggestion, you code for Main would be:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTableContent();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        { _.map(this.props.table,(row,index)=>{ // changed this line
            return (
              <TableItems
                key={index}
                index={index}
                row={row}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </tbody>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {table: state.table};
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps,{fetchTableContent})(Main);
```

Hope this helpers!
Cheers

Comment: you are right, I didn't use the above method but as you said I was not using setState, I tried that and it worked.  I implemented the above code, it is not working. Thank you for trying

Comment: so using `setState` worked and using `this.props.table` directly didn't? I am really curious to understand why that happens. Could you show the reducer code in your question?

Comment: Yes, to be clear, I used the promise from fetchTable content and then I set the state to it.  See the fetchTableContent now. I've updated

Comment: I see... This makes it work, but the only problem with this approach is that I don't see why you're using redux in your code... You're mixing two solutions (redux and "vanilla" state) for the same thing (state management). I recommend choosing and sticking to only one.

Comment: Yeah I know I'm not doing it in a right way.. Just started learning will soon correct it. Thanks for reaching me out

Answer (score 0):

I might just not be familiar with the syntax your using but i think the render function needs to look like what i put below

```
    render(){
return(
     <tbody>
         { this.state.rows.map((row,index)=>{
             return(
                  <TableItems
                      key={index}
                      index={index}
                      row={row}
                      />
                    );
                })
                }
      </tbody>)}
```

Map is being called on this.state.rows now. If you pass it inside the parentheses you are handing it in as a function, im not sure what kind of issues that would cause.

Comment: No it is not working it says map is not a function that's why i chose this

Comment: waht does the data in this.state.rows look like?

Comment: It is an array of data containing the above parameters like name, grade and occupation

Comment: an array of objects? or an array of arrays? or just a  flat array?

Comment: array of objects

Comment: the only thing i can think of is if this.state.row = {somename: [ {"name":steve , "grade":"D", "occupation":"this issue"},] } you would get this issue and you could fix it by passing this.state.rows.somename aside from that im out of ideas with out actually seeing a sample of this.state.rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179949/discussion-between-gowtham-koushik-and-steve-bohmbach).